# how to store EditText user input into a string variable in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to pass this variable as a parameter for a http call to my php file that inserts it into a database. If I create strings and manually set it, everything works. But when I try to use user input my app crashes. I am thinking I am having trouble storing user input from EditText into a string variable in c#. I read in java people use .getText().toString() but c# doesnt have getText(). I have tried this:

```
EditText usernameText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editUsername);
string username = usernameText.Text;
```

I have also tried:

```
string username = usernameText.toString();
```

Comment: `...my app crashes...` Add the Exception/Stacktrace to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now in c# you should do something like this

```
string str = edittext.text;
```